# How to keep splash screen from breaking main window positioning?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, splash-screen, multiple-monitors

I have a monitoring application that automatically positions it's main window on a secondary monitor (if available).

I'm trying to add a "splash screen" with a memo to show progress at startup. I want the splash screen to show on the main (default) monitor for 10 seconds (remaining visible after the main window appears, but the splash has controls so it may be manually closed too).  The splash screen appears as expected early in the initialization, but when it is present, the code I use to move the main form to the secondary monitor stops working. The main form ends up positioning itself at the upper left of the main monitor.  I have verified that the same monitor count and the same pixel dimensions are reported whether or not the splash form is shown.

Here's the code I use to position the main form:

```
if ExtraMonitorToUse < screen.monitorcount then  // it is available for use
  with screen.monitors[ExtraMonitorToUse] do // set the main form to top left of selected monitor
  begin
    WriteGenLog(format('Self: original coordinates: L%d T%d <--- screen.monitors: L%d, T%d ',[self.left, self.top, left, top]), true);
    self.left := left;
    self.top := top;
    WriteGenLog(format('Self: new coordinates: L%d T%d  ', [self.left, self.top]), true);
    WriteGenLog(format('Moved form to Monitor %d ', [Monitornum]), true);
  end;
```

Here's how I created the splash screen:  (in the DPR file of the application)

```
begin
  { Create the splash Screen }
  Splash := TSplash.Create(Application);
  { Show the splash Screen }
  Splash.show;
  { Update the splash Screen so that all components on it are
     visible }
  Splash.update;


  Application.Initialize;
  <..... snip .... >
end;
```

If I comment out the lines above "Application.Initialize" in the preceding code block, the main form positioning works properly. 
Why does creating the Splash form cause the positioning of the main form to stop working?

Edit - further information from log files......

Here is the log result with the splash screen enabled:

```
Monitor 0 Primary
Monitor 0 Workarea L0 T0 R1920 B1200
Monitor 0 Workarea L0 T0 R1920 B1200
Monitor 1 Workarea L1920 T0 R2560 B480
Monitor 1 Workarea L1920 T0 R2560 B480
Self: original coordinates: L268 T142 <--- screen.monitors: L1920, T0 
Self: new coordinates: L1920 T0  
Moved form to Monitor 1
```

Here is the log result with the splash screen commented out:

```
Monitor 0 Primary
Monitor 0 Workarea L0 T0 R1920 B1200
Monitor 0 Workarea L0 T0 R1920 B1200
Monitor 1 Workarea L1920 T0 R2560 B480
Monitor 1 Workarea L1920 T0 R2560 B480
Self: original coordinates: L268 T142 <--- screen.monitors: L1920, T0 
Self: new coordinates: L1920 T0  
Moved form to Monitor 1
```

Everything is the same in terms of the reported positions. But the change of position of "self" does not work.  It is not getting confused with the Splash screen either, because the position of the splash screen also remains centered on the main monitor.

Comment: I would assume that your splash screen code messes up one or more of your variables. For example, by setting left and top to zero before they get assigned to self.left and self.top. Print out all related variables directly before the `self.left:=left` line and compare the output with splash screen to the one without.

Comment: I edited above to add some additional variable status both with and without the splash screen enabled. There is no difference. It is confirmed that "self" is referring to the same form (MainForm) in each case, as the original position remains identical.

Comment: One interesting point is that the main form does actually move. It ends up on the main monitor at the upper left position (0,0) after executing the code, even though it reports itself as being at (1920,0)

Comment: In case form position setting may be interfering, AFAIR least intrusive positioning was poDesigned.

Comment: Whenever i had trouble with form positioning it was due to the `Position` or `DefaultMonitor` properties. I created my own Form Base Class which sets `Position` to `poDesigned` and `DefaultMonitor` to `dmDesktop` in it's constructor.